# What is the best way to make purple butter icing?

Tags: baking, coloring, icing

Will mixing red and blue food couloring work or is there a better method?

Comment: related : [Would the same mixing principles that apply to paint work for Food Coloring variations?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/would-the-same-mixing-principles-that-apply-to-paint-work-for-food-coloring-varia)

Comment: Yes. Pigment is a matter of subtractive mixing, while light is additive. In basic terms, all pigments operate on the same basic principles when mixing. Light behaves differently but isn't really germane here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Buy purple food colouring. any baking supply store will have it, and there are plenty of suppliers online. Powdered colour is much more intense than liquid.

Comment: Can't get purple food coloring here in new zealand for some weird reason. Been unable to get it for a couple of years I was told. So weird. I found an old one and used that.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to get that color with a blueberry juice or maybe beets, but purple food coloring would be easiest.

Comment: Beet juice is distinctly red. Blueberries are a very good idea though, and hey, more flavour! Purple carrots might also work, but I have never juiced them.

Answer (score 3):

I think that for casual home use, mixing your own blue and red is a perfectly fine idea. I've done it for making playdough and it is just fine. You could experiment with a few drops in water to determine the blue-to-red ratio, but unless you need a really specific color (Minnesota Vikings Purple or somesuch), just using equal amounts is fine.